# Why won't my popups close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Site: http://bit.ly/1dPAXsS

I can't figure out why my popups won't close. Have been debugging for too long 0_o
Click "Credit Card Inform Me When Available" to open popup

I have the following js:

```
// Popup
jQuery(".showpop").click(function () {

    var NewHeight = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    jQuery("#light").css({
        'top': NewHeight + 'px'
    });
    jQuery("#light").show();
    jQuery("#fade").show();
});
jQuery(".hidepop").click(function () {
    jQuery("#light").hide();
    jQuery("#fade").hide();
    return false;
});
```

I have tried using $ instead of jQuery, changed the target ids/classes and it still won't close.

This is similar to http://jsfiddle.net/techrevolt/K2TBa/

Comment: They all close for me.

Comment: Check your console for errors. I'm seeing a few too long to post.

Comment: The one on his site doesn't close. Not sure what the point was in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Please replicate the problem in the fiddle...

Comment: You're getting a javascript error which is most likely causing the issue. Check the console and fix the issue and it could very well resolve this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element was not loaded on the page when you made the call. What you want to do is wrap in a jquery document ready call like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hidepop").click(function(){
        $("#light").hide();
        $("#fade").hide();
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: thanks mate, that works. I don't need to wrap the entire code and .show code just the .hide code correct?

Comment: It is always good to wrap your event hooks inside of the document ready function. Because that fires when the dom is ready and that all your elements are on the page, ready to be called by jQuery.